# Is there way to convert dynamic to DynamicObject

Tags: c#

I got stuck in my code, where my LINQ Select clause returns Anonymous Type. I try to add each anonymous type to List. Items get added successfully, But the Class which has this method is generic class which inherits Interface1, all the class which inherits from this Iterface1 has method return type to be T

For example:

```
Interface Interface1<T>
{
    List<T> GetData();
    List<T> GetCalculatedValues();
}
```

I Created a class

```
public class DemoClass: Interface1<dynamic>
{
    List<dynamic> GetData()
    {
        //LINQ which return anonymous object type 
        return list<dynamic>;
    }

    List<dynamic> GetCalculatedValues()
    {
        //LINQ which return anonymous object type 
        return list<dynamic>;

    }
}
```

I Cannot Create any Strong Type Class, Since LINQ Query returns Anonymous type object where Properties cannot be defined before hand.

I need some suggestion, how to convert dynamic to DynamicObject , Is there way to do . I don't want to have Object has Type T. Apart from Object type , Can we have casting Dynamic Object. or any one has implemented DuckTyping in C#. Will DuckType will help in this scenario.

Comment: Does your solution with `dynamic` work?

Comment: Use var keyword, it'll provide IEnumerable<T> If linq query returns collection of anonymous objects

Comment: Can you show us the code that is creating the anonymous types? Generally, you should either use the var keyword to reference the type where possible, or create a new named type to hold your data, and use Linq methods to return that type instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: `I Cannot Create any Strong Type Class`  Oh really, and why is that?  I can't think of any possible circumstance in which you could create an anonymous type but not a named type.

Comment: Im using Dynamic LINQ Library and getting Anonymous Type out of it.